# jQuery use variable as event?

Tags: jquery, events, variables, triggers

Is there a way in jQuery or javascript to trigger a variable string as an event?

ex.

```
if (a == b) {
    x = "$('div').hide()";
} else {
    x = "$('div').show()";
}

*trigger x event here*
```

Ignore the fact that this isn't the correct way to do it.. It is only an example to make the question easier to understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `eval` function:

```
var x = '';
if (a == b) {
    x = "$('div').hide()";
} else {
    x = "$('div').show()";
}

eval(x);
```

Also you could simplify your code like this using the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method which obviously is a far better solution:

```
$('div').toggle(a == b);
```

Comment: aha. damn i totally forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a == b) {
    action = "hide";
} else {
    action = "show";
}

$('div')[action]();
```

Or you can use [`jQuery.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)